# How to make this query better (e.g. avoid repeating subquery in a query)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange

Stack Exchange provides access to query their MS SQL databases. They have a table `Posts` where each post is either a question or an answer (see the schema on right hand side [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/new)).

I saw a [query for questions answered by more than three 50k users](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/revision/1252021/1540600/questions-answered-by-more-than-3-top-n-users):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Q.Id AS [Post Link], Q.AnswerCount
FROM Posts Q
JOIN Posts A1 on A1.ParentId = Q.Id 
  AND A1.OwnerUserId IN (SELECT TOP ##TopN## Id FROM Users ORDER BY Reputation DESC)
JOIN Posts A2 on A2.ParentId = Q.Id
  AND A2.OwnerUserId IN (SELECT TOP ##TopN## Id FROM Users ORDER BY Reputation DESC)
  AND A1.Id != A2.Id
JOIN Posts A3 on A3.ParentId = Q.Id
  AND A3.OwnerUserId IN (SELECT TOP ##TopN## Id FROM Users ORDER BY Reputation DESC)
  AND A3.Id != A1.Id AND A3.Id != A2.Id
WHERE Q.AnswerCount = 3
```

I was wondering how to improve the query (balance between efficiency and readability)? For example:

- Is it possible to avoid repeating the subquery `SELECT TOP ##TopN## Id FROM Users ORDER BY Reputation DESC` three times, and instead just have it once?
- Will it be more  efficient if switching the order of filtering out questions with less than three answers and checking if  a question is answered by more than three 50k users?

Comment: Your title should state what your code does. Please read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: As the author of the SEDE query, (1) I'm happy that the (extensive!) version history of that query seems to be gone, and (2) because SQL class was 20 years ago, I started off with a simpler goal (static 50k) and eventually figured out how to incorporate the variable "top N".

Comment: Re-viewing my own query, it's also apparent that I intended to find Q's with *at least 3* answers by top-rated users, but have managed to restrict it to Q's with *exactly 3* such answers.

Comment: Hrmph; after incorporating [Gert's improvements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/244191/103675), the link to the SEDE query has also changed.  https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/revision/1252021/1540600/questions-answered-by-more-than-3-top-n-users is the one for this question.

Answer (score 2):

The query title is

> Questions answered by more than 3 50k users

But that doesn't describe what the query actually does. The query selects questions with three answers given by three *distinct* top `n` rated users. They happen to have more than 50k rep on that site, but that's a mere coincidence.

That can also be done by this query, containing only 1 subquery to get the top rated users:

```sql
SELECT Q.Id AS [Post Link], Q.AnswerCount
FROM Posts Q
WHERE Q.AnswerCount = 3
AND
(
  SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT A.OwnerUserId)
  FROM Posts A
  WHERE A.ParentId = Q.Id
  AND A.OwnerUserId IN
  (
    SELECT TOP ##TopN## Id
    FROM Users
    ORDER BY Reputation DESC
  )
) = 3
```

For the record, the query doing what the title says would be

```sql
SELECT Q.Id AS [Post Link], Q.AnswerCount
FROM Posts Q
WHERE Q.AnswerCount >= 3
AND
(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.OwnerUserId)
  FROM Posts A
  JOIN Users U ON A.OwnerUserId = U.Id
  WHERE A.ParentId = Q.Id
  AND U.Reputation >= 50000
) = Q.AnswerCount
```

Assuming that the intention was to get questions with answers from 50k users *exclusively*.